# Error connecting UWP app to Arduino by USB

Tags: c#, arduino, uwp, windowsiot

I am following this tutorial, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/wra. Code:

```
using Microsoft.Maker.RemoteWiring;
using Microsoft.Maker.Serial;
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    IStream connection;
    RemoteDevice arduino;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        connection = new UsbSerial("VID_2341", "PID_0043");
        arduino = new RemoteDevice(connection);
        connection.ConnectionEstablished += OnConnectionEstablished;
        connection.begin(9600, SerialConfig.SERIAL_8N1);
    }
    private void OnConnectionEstablished()
    {
        var action = Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler( ()=>
        {
            onbutton.IsEnabled = true;
            offbutton.IsEnabled = true;
        }));
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is

> Additional information: Requested Windows Runtime type 'Microsoft.Maker.Serial.UsbSerial' is not registered.

for line

```
        connection = new UsbSerial("VID_2341", "PID_0043");
```

Update: AppManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build">

  <Identity Name="76b9fbdc-32fc-4b66-9ce0-b3e91c83850b" Publisher="CN=Ramy" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x86"/>
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="76b9fbdc-32fc-4b66-9ce0-b3e91c83850b" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>ArduinoApp</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Ramy</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0" MinVersion="1.0.23819.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug" MinVersion="14.0.23918.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"/>
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="EN-US"/>
    <Resource uap:Scale="200"/>

  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="ArduinoApp.exe" EntryPoint="ArduinoApp.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="ArduinoApp" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="ArduinoApp" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png"/>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.StringCallbackEventArgs" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.UwpFirmata" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.CallbackEventArgs" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.SystemResetCallbackEventArgs" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.SysexCallbackEventArgs" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Firmata.I2cCallbackEventArgs" ThreadingModel="both"/>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>Microsoft.Maker.RemoteWiring.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.RemoteWiring.RemoteDevice" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.RemoteWiring.HardwareProfile" ThreadingModel="both"/>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>Microsoft.Maker.Serial.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.UsbSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.BleSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.DfRobotBleSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.NetworkSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.BluetoothSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="Microsoft.Maker.Serial.CurieBleSerial" ThreadingModel="both"/>
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
  <build:Metadata>
    <build:Item Name="TargetFrameworkMoniker" Value=".NETCore,Version=v5.0"/>
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudio" Version="14.0"/>
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudioEdition" Value="Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015"/>
    <build:Item Name="OperatingSystem" Version="10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)"/>
    <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll" Version="14.0.25123.0"/>
    <build:Item Name="ProjectGUID" Value="{F5FCE15E-EDD1-4F69-AF51-2232E7915910}"/>
    <build:Item Name="OptimizingToolset" Value="None"/>
    <build:Item Name="TargetRuntime" Value="Managed"/>
    <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.dll" Version="14.0.25219.0"/>
    <build:Item Name="MakePri.exe" Version="10.0.10586.212 (th2_release_sec.160328-1908)"/>
  </build:Metadata>
</Package>
```

Comment: Have you got the appropriate projects referenced in your app, and registered correctly in the  manifest? VS should do this for you but sometimes it doesn't work. Can you post the `AppxManifest.xml` file you get if you build a Store package and then extract it (.appx can be renamed to .zip)

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It is included in the app manifest.

Comment: What kind of your Arduino board?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Arduino Uno R3 with ATmega328 chip.